# virtualbox on windows: how to make virtualbox and vm separate taskbar icons

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

The virtualbox is one icon at the task bar, when I click it, it becomes 2, one is virtualbox application and the other is the vm. Somehow this is annoying to me, is there a way to make them separate icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running just one VM, one simple solution is to close the VirtualBox Manager window. The VM will continue running.